# How to get image value of my UITabBarItem when using StoryBoard Reference?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, uitabbar

I have an error when I use **StoryBoard Reference** after a `UITabBarController` (which is a custom one).

I found how to customise my icon image, but in my code, when I try to get this image, the value doesn't exist.

Here is my **image configuration**:

[image: Image configuration]

And there the error when I run my app:

[image: Error]

It worked before I used a Storyboard Reference. And the Image is set as my other Tab Bar Items, so I don't understand why I get this error when I run my app.

---

**EDIT: Where do I call the `setup()` function?**

I have 3 files to handle my Tab Bar.

The first one, `CustomTabBarController.swift`, contains this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let customTabBar = CustomTabBar(frame: self.tabBar.frame)
customTabBar.datasource = self
customTabBar.delegate = self
customTabBar.setup()
```

It calls the `setup()` method of `CustomTabBar`, which is:

```
func setup() {
    // get tab bar items from default tab bar
    tabBarItems = datasource.tabBarItemsInCustomTabBar(self)

    customTabBarItems = []
    tabBarButtons = []

    selectedTabBarItemIndex = 0

    let containers = createTabBarItemContainers()
    createTabBarItems(containers)

    customTabBarItems[selectedTabBarItemIndex].iconView.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.44, green:0.52, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
}
```

This function calls the `setup()` function of my `CustomTabBarItem` view:

```
func createTabBarItems(_ containers: [CGRect]) {

    var index = 0
    for item in tabBarItems {
        let container = containers[index]

        let customTabBarItem = CustomTabBarItem(frame: container)
        customTabBarItem.setup(item) // HERE I call my setup() method of my Tab Bar Item

        self.addSubview(customTabBarItem)
        customTabBarItems.append(customTabBarItem)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.width, height: container.height))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomTabBar.barItemTapped(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        customTabBarItem.addSubview(button)
        tabBarButtons.append(button)

        index += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: `setup()` is being called before the image is laid out. Where are you calling the method?

Comment: I edited my first post to answer your question. Does it help?

Comment: Inside of `CustomTabBar.swift` do you have `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method implemented? And if so, are you calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` inside?

Comment: I didn't call it, I added it and I still have the same error. It is strange because it work for items images which are not linked to a storyboard reference...

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something to fix the problem, *but I still don't know how to explain it*.

**What I did:** I added a Tab Bar Item in the storyboard which was referenced in my `Main storyboard`. Then I put my image on this item, and it works correctly.

[image: Problem solved]